# Inserting an iterated value into a set

Tags: rust

I have the following code and error message.

```rs
fn my_func<K: Ord, V: Ord>(my_map: BTreeMap<K, BTreeSet<V>>, a: K, b: K) -> bool {
  let mut added = false;
  for x in my_map.get(&a).unwrap() {
    added = added | my_map.get_mut(&b).unwrap().insert(x);
    //                                                 ^ expected type parameter `V`, found `&V`
  }
  added
}
```

How can I insert a value of type `V` into the set in `my_map`?

Answer (score 0):

1. `my_map` owns all the `BTreeSet<V>`s, and therefore all the `V`s in the map.
2. Each `V` can only be owned once, so each value in the map can be present in only one slot. Therefore you cannot look up the value in one slot (key-value pair) and just store it in another since then it would be owned by two slots.

You can either:

1. `clone()` each value before inserting it in another slot, after which you have two different values each owned by their own slot.
2. Require V to be of type [`Rc<_>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) which (through indirection and reference counting) allows two slots to point to the same value.

These can be implemented as follows:

1. Change the end of line 4 to `.insert(x.clone());`
2. Same as 1. and also change the `my_map` parameter on line 1 to `my_map: BTreeMap<K, BTreeSet<Rc<V>>>`

The difference between these is that if you later modify a value in the map which has been duplicated to multiple slots using your function:

1. The values are all different, so modifying one does not affect the others
2. The value inside the `Rc` is shared and so modifying one changes all values in the map

Comment: The first sentence is confusingly worded: even if `V` did have lifetimes, `my_map` would still own `V`s outright, and *adding* constraints can't make an owned thing not-owned. There's also no "implicit `'static`" thing going on like can sometimes happen with `Box<dyn Trait>`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am still a bit new to these things.. You might very well be right.

Comment: I made some edits that fix the issue I noticed earlier; in broad terms the analysis is correct. However, I don't think the suggested fix works, since `my_map.get(&a)` returns a reference which overlaps with the later call to `get_mut`. Maybe something another `clone` could fix.